# Sampling with independent probabilities

Tags: probability, sampling

I'm looking for one specific sampling method that decides about inclusion probability of each item regardless of existence of other elements.
As an example given 0.5 as the inclusion probability, it toss a coin for each element to decide about its inclusion.

This is **different** from **fixed size sampling** methods like sampling with replacement and without replacement as in this method only inclusion probability is provided and **not** the sample size.

Now I need more information about this method like the name of method, the probability of having different sizes for the sample and ...

Thanks.

Comment: @Ilham. OK to suggest stats (crossvalidated) for an additional post, but not as a substitute for math. There is a reason we have tags for sampling, statistics, etc. on this site. Answers from the two sites can be quite different in rigor and approach. Meanwhile, I'll try to resist giving advice to those who ask questions in real and complex analysis, subjects in which I don't consider myself to be an up to date expert.

Comment: @Ilham: Notice that my comment about giving advice mentioned _my self-imposed_ restriction to try not to comment on topics beyond my depth. It is obvious that not everyone shares this sort of inhibition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to know the application you have in mind. In some
applications this is called 'random thinning'. You may want to
search the Internet for that phrase.

For example, suppose you have a Poisson process. You may choose
(or only be capable of) selecting or observing only a fraction $p$ of the events at random.
In this application, if the parent Poisson process has rate $\lambda$,
then the sampled or observed process is again Poisson, but
with rate $p\lambda.$ In such a context, random thinning is
sometimes called 'filtering'.

In Markov Chain Monte Carlo procedures, the $B$ generated points
will typically not be independent. By deterministic thinning
(say selecting every tenth point) or random thinning (selecting
one tenth of the points at random) one obtains a sample that
is essentially iid. The sparseness of the thinning depends
on the autocorrelation function (ACF) of $B$ points generated by the MCMC procedure. If random thinning
is used the thinned sample size will be binomial with mean $B/10$.

In Monte Carlo integration, certain kinds of 'acceptance sampling'
sample at random without a fixed sample size.

In certain kinds of 'cluster sampling' of, say, a human
population, one may sample census tracts (clusters) at random and
then sample households within tracts at random. One or both
of the phases of sampling may be proportional rather than
based on a fixed sample size. Similar schemes are used in
sampling plants or animals. The main motivation here is that
it is more convenient or efficient to sample within clusters than randomly
across the entire population.

These are three examples that I have encountered personally.
And there are others I have not mentioned. The difficulty
is that the terminology seems to change depending on the
type of application. Maybe if you google some of the phrases
I have put in quotes, you will find exactly what you want.

I hope some of this is helpful. If not, perhaps you can be more specific about your application and
the reason for selecting without a fixed sample size.
Then perhaps I--or someone else--can give a more targeted
answer.